# Cucumber Scenario Outline only ran once, even it have 3 scenarios

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, gherkin

- .feature file:

```
Feature: Test Log In Functionality

  Scenario: The user should be able to login with correct userName & Password
    Given user is on Login Page
    When user enters the correct UserName & Password
    Then user gets the Confirmation

  Scenario Outline: User should Log In with below credentials
    Given user is on Login Page
    When user enters the correct Email <UserName>
    And user enters the correct Password <Password>
    And user enters the Log In Button
    Then user gets the Confirmation

    Examples: 
      | UserName             | Password  |
      | shoryak3@outlook.com | Test@1234 |
      | tim@Testmail.com     | trpass    |
      | Rich@TestMail.com    | rwpass    |
```

Answer (score 1):

I have quickly checked your feature file. i hope `- .feature file:` line is not part of your feature file. If its then you will get `cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: gherkin.ParserException$CompositeParserException: Parser errors:`

after running your feature file I can see that its working absolutly fine without any issue. Please refer below screenshot for your reference. try to restart your intellij and run it one more time

[image]